# Phone call on textview tap

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this fragment with a two columns list view, the second of which has phone numbers in it. I'm trying to make those numbers clickable, in order to make a phone call (using an Intent). Problem is when I run the app, nothing happens on tapping the text.

(Note that i've already set the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

in the manifest).

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    ListView lview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
    populateList();
    listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);
final TextView tv= (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.rows, null).findViewById(R.id.number);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phone_no=tv.getText().toString().trim();
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_no));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }});
return view;
}
```

rows.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/number"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:clickable="true"
 />



</LinearLayout>
```

listviewAdapter.java

```
public class listviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "Column 1";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Column 2";

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    Activity activity;

    public listviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtFirst;
        TextView txtSecond;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

fragment_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put your number `TextView` in `fragment_my.xml` file

Comment: Why aren't you setting `onClickListener` on `tv` in your `getView` of `listviewAdapter`?

Comment: Tried both, still nothing :/

Comment: Updated the question with listviewAdapter and fragment_my.xml